# Responsive css footer with 3 columns

Tags: html, css

i have this CSS code with media queries:

```
#footer-top {
    width:100%;
    height:480px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom:2px #000000 solid;
}
#footer-left {
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-right:1px #000000 solid;
}
#footer-middle {
    width: 294px; /* Account for margins + border values */
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-right:1px #000000 solid;
}
#footer-right {
    width: 270px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
}
#footer-bottom {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    #footer-left {
        width: 41%;
        padding: 1% 4%;
    }
    #footer-middle {
        width: 41%;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        float: right;
    }
    #footer-right {
        clear: both;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }
    #footer-bottom {
        padding: 1% 4%;
    }
}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #footer-left {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }
    #footer-middle {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #footer-right {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }
}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #footer-right {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

so im trying to make my footer responsive for smaller screens etc.

I have created a fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/VMn7Y/ so you can see the full HTML too, but as you shrink the screen size the footer-right div is starting to display over the footer-bottom div. how do i make it so as the screen gets smaller, the footer-bottom div will be pushed down?

Comment: I would ditch the floats and go with `display:inline-block;` instead on the #footer-left/-middle/-right

Comment: still got the same issue with the footer-right div overlapping the footer-bottom div :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition to my comment to complete the answer is to remove the `height:480px` from `#footer-top` example --- > http://jsfiddle.net/VMn7Y/17/

Hope that's how you wanted it!

Comment: excellent - that looks better. How about the main #footer div? at the moment then height is 580px which is fine but when the screen gets smaller that heigh gets bigger so how will i change this so the background (height of #footer) expands as well? - http://jsfiddle.net/rFv8H/

Comment: Can the height just be `auto` (or just have `height:580px;` deleted)? I'm not sure I understand the question exactly the fiddle isn't really making my mind understand

Comment: ok ive added the footer and footer-inner elements onto the css here - http://jsfiddle.net/VMn7Y/28/ is you make the screen width smaller you will see at the bottom of the footer there is white space where the footers height is not expanding

Comment: its ok looks like its ok now - i removed the height and that worked :) cheers

Comment: Sorry I couldn't quite get the last part, but very glad it worked out! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you use media queries it's easier to get better results if you start from smaller screen sizes and work your way up.

I've fixed your fiddle, basically all you needed to do was change your width to 30% (or 27% in this case considering your padding)

Check it here:

```
float:left;
padding: 5px 10px;
width:27%;
```

[fixed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMn7Y/20/)

Comment: i dont want each one column a % of the page width otherwise they wont display below each other as the page gets smaller. they will just shrink and the content wont be readable

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, yes removing the height will help, anyways about the media queries thing you should consider staring from smaller screen sizes, It'll make you life a lot easier :)

Comment: Also you should check min-height and max-height regarding your other question

Comment: right okay - il give it a go starting from smaller - cheers. what would you suggest doing for the min-height and max-height.. have you got a code example please?